# how do I set monit to non-daemon mode

Tags: command-line-interface, monit, daemon

I'm trying to get monit to just excite the monitrc script once and then exit.

I've tried

> monit -v -Ic /tmp/monitrc

but when I look at the output it says:

```
Runtime constants:
 Control file       = /tmp/monitrc
 Log file           = (not defined)
 Pid file           = /home/hduser/.monit.pid
 Id file            = /home/hduser/.monit.id
 State file         = /home/hduser/.monit.state
 Debug              = True
 Log                = False
 Use syslog         = False
 Is Daemon          = True
```

Not sure if these some other switch to put in, or does monit not support this?